# Number of elements required to occur at least ones in each set of a set

Tags: algorithm, set-theory

I have a list *L* of lists *l[i]* of elements *e*. I am looking for an algorithm that finds a minimum set *S_min* of elements such that at least one member of *S_min* occurs in each *l*.

I am not only curious to find a simple algorithm that does this for me, but also to learn what problems of this sort are actually called. I am sure there is something out there

I have implemented brute force algorithms that start with adding all those elements to *S_min* which occur in sets of *len(l[i])=1*. The rest is simple trial and error.

Comment: If `L = {{1}, {2,3}}`, what is `S_min` then? Could you give more examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe ist the [vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Vertex_cover_in_hypergraphs) in hypergraphs, an optimization problem which is NP-hard in the general case but admits approximation algorithms for suitably bounded instances.